# ElementCollection: failed to lazily initialize a collection, no session or

Tags: hibernate, jsf, uielementcollection

I have a field with a set of String to save and edit the value of selectManyCheckbox. I use the annotation @ElementCollection as described in 
http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnbqa.html 
I can save at the first time but by saving at the second time I got the following exception:

> Caused by: javax.servlet.ServletException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection, no session or session was closed    at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:606)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:329)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.primefaces.webapp.filter.FileUploadFilter.doFilter(FileUploadFilter.java:79)
>   [primefaces-3.3.jar:]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.weld.servlet.ConversationPropagationFilter.doFilter(ConversationPropagationFilter.java:62)
>   [weld-core-1.1.5.AS71.Final.jar:2012-02-10 15:31]     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:280)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:248)
>   [jbossweb-7.0.10.Final.jar:]  at
>   org.jboss.solder.servlet.exception.CatchExceptionFilter.doFilter(CatchExceptionFilter.java:65)
>   [solder-impl-3.1.0.Final.jar:3.1.0.Final]     ... 29 more Caused by:
>   org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize
>   a collection, no session or session was closed    at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationException(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:393)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.throwLazyInitializationExceptionIfNotConnected(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:385)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.AbstractPersistentCollection.initialize(AbstractPersistentCollection.java:378)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentSet.add(PersistentSet.java:206)
>   [hibernate-core-4.0.1.Final.jar:4.0.1.Final]  at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValuesForModel(MenuRenderer.java:382)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.convertSelectManyValue(MenuRenderer.java:129)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.MenuRenderer.getConvertedValue(MenuRenderer.java:315)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.getConvertedValue(UIInput.java:1030)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.validate(UIInput.java:960)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.executeValidate(UIInput.java:1233)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIInput.processValidators(UIInput.java:698)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIForm.processValidators(UIForm.java:253)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.processValidators(UIComponentBase.java:1214)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   javax.faces.component.UIViewRoot.processValidators(UIViewRoot.java:1172)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ProcessValidationsPhase.execute(ProcessValidationsPhase.java:76)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.execute(LifecycleImpl.java:118)
>   [jsf-impl-2.1.5-jbossorg-1.jar:2.1.5-SNAPSHOT]    at
>   org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.execute(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:95)
>   [myfaces-extcdi-jsf20-module-impl-1.0.5.jar:1.0.5]    at
>   javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:593)
>   [jboss-jsf-api_2.1_spec-2.0.0.Final.jar:2.0.0.Final]  ... 38 more

I use JBOSS 7.1.0-Final, Hibernate 4.0.1.Final and JSF 2.0

Following are my codes:

**Test.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Test.FIND_BY_ID, query = "select test from Test test where test.id = :id")
})
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7294677843656741933L;

    public static final String FIND_BY_ID = "test.by.id";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Set<String> textes;


    public Test() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<String> getTextes() {
        return textes;
    }

    public void setTextes(Set<String> textes) {
        this.textes = textes;
    }
}
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.test.textes}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="Option 3" />  
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>

        <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{formBean.saveTest}" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Following are the related sources:

**FormBean.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class FormBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6484233109393875203L;

    @EJB
    private ServiceBean serviceBean;

    private Test test;

    public String saveTest() {
        serviceBean.save(test);
        return "test";
    }

    public String createTest() {
        test = new Test();
        return "test";
    }

    public Test getTest() {
        return test;
    }

    public void setTest(Test test) {
        this.test = test;
    }

}
```

**ServiceBean.java**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ServiceBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public boolean save(Test test) {
        Test dbTest = findTestById(test.getId());
        if (dbTest == null) {
            entityManager.persist(test);
        }
        else {
            entityManager.merge(test);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Test findTestById(Long id) {
        if (id == null)
            return null;

        TypedQuery<Test> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Test.FIND_BY_ID, Test.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        List<Test> results = query.getResultList();

        if (results.isEmpty())
            return null;

        return results.get(0);
    }
}
```

**test_index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="Test" action="#{formBean.createTest()}" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thanks for helps
Nguyen

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution for this problem, which is already publiced in: 
[@ElementCollection](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Persistence/ElementCollection)

Following is my solution:

**Test.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "TEST")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name = Test.FIND_BY_ID, query = "select test from Test test where test.id = :id")
})
public class Test implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7294677843656741933L;

    public static final String FIND_BY_ID = "test.by.id";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Long id;

    @ElementCollection
    private Set<String> textes;

    public Test() {
    }

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Set<String> getTextes() {
        return textes;
    }

    public void setTextes(Set<String> textes) {
        this.textes = textes;
    }
}
```

**test.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<body>
    <h:form id="form">
        <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.selectedTextes}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2" />  
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 3" itemValue="Option 3" />  
        </h:selectManyCheckbox>

        <h:commandButton value="Save" action="#{formBean.saveTest}" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

**FormBean.java**

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class FormBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 6484233109393875203L;

    @EJB
    private ServiceBean serviceBean;

    private Test test;

    private Set<String> selectedTextes;

    public String saveTest() {
        serviceBean.save(test, selectedTextes);
        return "test";
    }

    public String createTest() {
        test = new Test();
        return "test";
    }

    // getters and setters
}
```

**ServiceBean.java**

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class ServiceBean {

    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    public boolean save(Test test, Set<String> selectedTextes) {
        Test dbTest = findTestById(test.getId());
        if (dbTest == null) {
            if (selectedTextes != null) {
                test.setTextes(selectedTextes);
            }
            entityManager.persist(test);
        }
        else {
            if (selectedTextes != null) {
                dbTest.setTextes(selectedTextes);
            }
            entityManager.merge(dbTest);
        }

        return true;
    }

    public Test findTestById(Long id) {
        if (id == null)
            return null;

        TypedQuery<Test> query = entityManager.createNamedQuery(Test.FIND_BY_ID, Test.class);
        query.setParameter("id", id);
        List<Test> results = query.getResultList();

        if (results.isEmpty())
            return null;

        return results.get(0);
    }
}
```

**test_index.xhtml**

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
    xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
    xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
    xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
    xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">

<body>
    <h:form>
        <h:commandLink value="Test" action="#{formBean.createTest()}" />
    </h:form>
</body>
</html>
```

Nguyen

Comment: Rejected edit (which should have been a comment) by [dc360](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1352408/dc360): Can you please also state what you changed? The link you posted although good is several pages long.

Answer (score 0):

The diff from question to answer:

```
***************
*** 14,18 ****
        private Long id;

!       @ElementCollection(fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
        private Set<String> textes;

--- 14,18 ----
        private Long id;

!       @ElementCollection
        private Set<String> textes;

***************
*** 47,51 ****
      <body>
        <h:form id="form">
!           <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.test.textes}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />
                  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2" />
--- 47,51 ----
      <body>
        <h:form id="form">
!           <h:selectManyCheckbox value="#{formBean.selectedTextes}">
                <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 1" itemValue="Option 1" />
                  <f:selectItem itemLabel="Option 2" itemValue="Option 2" />
***************
*** 70,75 ****
        private Test test;

        public String saveTest() {
!           serviceBean.save(test);
            return "test";
        }
--- 70,77 ----
        private Test test;

+       private Set<String> selectedTextes;
+ 
        public String saveTest() {
!           serviceBean.save(test, selectedTextes);
            return "test";
        }
***************
*** 97,107 ****
        private EntityManager entityManager;

!       public boolean save(Test test) {
            Test dbTest = findTestById(test.getId());
            if (dbTest == null) {
                entityManager.persist(test);
            }
            else {
!               entityManager.merge(test);
            }

--- 99,115 ----
        private EntityManager entityManager;

!       public boolean save(Test test, Set<String> selectedTextes) {
            Test dbTest = findTestById(test.getId());
            if (dbTest == null) {
+               if (selectedTextes != null) {
+                   test.setTextes(selectedTextes);
+               }
                entityManager.persist(test);
            }
            else {
!               if (selectedTextes != null) {
!                   dbTest.setTextes(selectedTextes);
!               }
!               entityManager.merge(dbTest);
            }
```